# Where do I handle feathersjs/socketio-client connection error

Tags: socket.io, feathersjs

I'm using feathers with socketio in backend. The client is listening and everything works well.

I want to handle the 'server not responding' error and I don't find where can I do that?

The error thrown by the server:

```
"Unhandled promise rejection 
Object { type: "FeathersError", name: "Timeout", message: "Timeout of 5000ms exceeded calling find on newsfeed", code: 408, className: "timeout", data: {…}, errors: {}, stack: "FeathersError@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@feathersjs/errors/lib/index.js:58:19\nTimeout@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@feathersjs/errors/lib/index.js:135:3\nsend/</timeoutId<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@feathersjs/transport-commons/lib/client.js:66:9\n" }"
```

It is correct, the 'promise' is not handled! Where do I handle?

I tried adding catch on each line just to see what works but without success:

```
import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers'
import socketio from '@feathersjs/socketio-client'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socket = io('http://localhost:3030/', {transports: ['websocket']});
socket.on("connect_failed", er=>console.error('Error connecting to server: ', er));
const restApi = feathers()
  .configure(socketio(socket));

try {
  restApi.service('/newsfeed');
  restApi.on("connect_failed", er=>console.error('Error connecting to server: ', er));

}
catch (er) {
    console.error('Error connecting to server: ', er)
}

export default restApi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout error is coming from a particular request so you have to handle it wherever you are making the request.

`restApi.service('/newsfeed').find()`

If you're using async/await, you can wrap your service call in a try/catch or my personal favorite is just putting a catch on the call;

```js
// try/catch
try {
  const response= await restApi.service('/newsfeed').find();
catch(e) {
  // handle e
}

//just use catch
const response= await restApi.service('/newsfeed').find().catch(e => {
  // handle e
});
```

If you're using promises, just use  a catch:

```js
restApi.service('/newsfeed').find().then(response => {
  // handle response
}).catch(e => {
  // handle e
});
```

Comment: You are right but in this case it's about connecting to. Where I use`find` (or `get`, `post`, etc) of course I `catch` as the server send back several type of errors like forbidden/user not authenticated, etc, with custom error code.

Comment: I have a component that subscribes to the `disconnect`, `connect_timeout`, `connect` and `reconnect` events from the socket client (`restApi.io` in your case).

It handles showing/hiding a message when the API goes offline.  

All of the events are listed here: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect-error%E2%80%99

Comment: Cool! I have one too! (using Vue - it hide the screen and display only the status of: internet connection and API server availability. When I get 404 or other specific errors in regular calls, I turn it on. But here I don't know how to do it, how to catch the "404"(or similar) from socket.io. What I tried for cathing  ‘connect_error’ failed.

Comment: You can only listen to the events listed in the socket.io docs. These are all connection-level events.

To "listen" for 404s and other errors, you can either catch these and communicate the error to your other components or use error hooks.
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#application-hooks